# SL4A _R6 / Python4android_R4 webViewShow NullPointerException on simple example code

Tags: python, html, webview, sl4a

I'm trying to get a HTML Gui on my simple SL4A Python app. the only thing I need to perform is ask the user for 1 input string at the start of my app.

For debugging purposes I started of simple. Unfortunately even this won't function.
Any idea's what's wrong here? (I've tried several pieces of code like this and all have the same issue)

Python code:

```
import android

loop = True
droid = android.Android()
droid.webViewShow('/sdcard/sl4a/scripts/screen.html')

while loop:
    res = droid.waitForEvent('data')
    if res:
        print str(res)
```

HTML code

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var droid = new Android();
   var fiets = function() {
        droid.postEvent("data", document.getElementById("gsm").value);
      }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onload:"fiets()">
  <form onsubmit="fiets(); return false;">
   <label for="say">What would you like to say?</label>
   <input type="text" id="gsm" value="99999999" />
   <input type="submit" value="Store" />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

the error message is repeatedly (the number 3114 is incremental):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Result(id=3114, result=None, error=u'java.lang.NullPointerException')
```

update:

http://www.mithril.com.au/android/doc/EventFacade.html

As we go I read `waitForEvent` is deprecated in r4. I should use `eventWaitFor` instead.
This takes the error away but doesn't make the example function. Python script prints nothing.

update2:

`droid.postEvent` should become `droid.eventPost`

`droid.waitForEvent('data')` should become `droid.waitForEvent('data')`

In javascript and python.

Problem Solved